# Jade-if:s in javascript code

Tags: pug

In Jade, Using - if(...) { } works in html for me without problems. But when I use it in a javascript block, it doesn't work.

i.e. this:

```
script(type='text/javascript')
  - if(locals.Android) {
  settings.device = 'android';
  - }
```

outputs this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
- if(locals.Android) {
settings.device = 'android';
- }
</script>
```

and not this (when locals.Android === true):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
settings.device = 'android';
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the if() outside the `<script>` tag - that way, the `<script>` tag only gets output when `locals.Android === true`

eg.

```
if locals.Android === true
    script
        settings.device = 'android';
else
    //- no script tag, do something else?
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing

Comment: Would be faster too, as the DOM has one less js script to execute